# How to work on Python in iPad as if I'm working on a PC?

Tags: python, django, pandas, ipad

Is there any way to work with Python in iPad as I would on a PC? I will have quite some time with only my iPad and would like to continue with the same files.

I currently use Jupyter notebook and Sublime text, but I don't mind any other alternative that works on iPad.

I will be working on Python, Pandas, Django, Bokeh... just to give you an idea of what libraries I use.

Comment: It would be great if you have ideas for offline as well, as I will not always have internet. But online ideas are also very welcome.

Comment: This question belongs to [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Jupyter Notebooks as your front end, you could use something like [Microsoft Azure](https://notebooks.azure.com/) to act as your Jupyter server. The Python code runs on their cloud servers, so you don't need to have it installed locally.
Alternatively, if you have a Linux box available to you on your network, you could run [JupyterHub](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html) and connect to that via your iPad browser.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested to try [Juno Connect](https://juno.sh/junoconnect), it is a Jupyter Notebook client for iPad. It is a client though — so you will need a remote server running Jupyter to connect to.